# ContentSecurityPolicy data:image

Tags: laravel, content-security-policy

I decided to try using ContentSecurityPolicy, everything seems to work fine, but the images stopped loading, I get this error

> Request URL: data:image/jpeg;base64

What do I need to add to my ContentSecurityPolicy.php file to avoid this error?

This is what I have now

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContentSecurityPolicy
{
    public $resources = [
        'default-src' => [
            "'self'",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
            'fonts.gstatic.com',
            'code.jquery.com',
        ],
    ];

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $contentSecurityPolicy = '';
        foreach ($this->resources as $key => $values) {
            $contentSecurityPolicy .= $key . ' ' . implode(' ', $values);
        }

        $response->header("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src $contentSecurityPolicy");

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It told you exactly what kind of header it is missing. Try adding `data:` to your array. But you should consider using that props only for `img-src`. Because allowing `data:` for scripts etc. is not a good idea while adding CSP.

```
    public $resources = [
        'default-src' => [
            "'self'",
            "data:",
            "'unsafe-inline'",
            'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
            'fonts.gstatic.com',
            'code.jquery.com',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: I tried to do it like this `"img-src 'self' data:"`, everything seems to work

Comment: but now I have another problem, I also upload a video from YouTube using an iframe, and now this SecurityPolicy swears at this `Request URL: https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api`

Comment: helped `frame-src youtube.com www.youtube.com`